# Partial sum of the series $\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{r(r+1)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, summation

An [Exercise from Apostol's Introduction to Analytic Number Theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=Il64dZELHEIC&pg=PA102) which I am not able to solve.

Let $\mathsf{S_{n}}$ denote the $n$-th partial sum of the series: $$\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{r(r+1)}$$

Prove that for every integer $k>1$, there exists integers $m$ and $n$, such that $$s_{m}-s_{n} =\frac{1}{k}$$

Comment: You know you can use partial fraction decomposition on your summand, yes?

Comment: $s_m - s_n < 1/2$ so how can this be true for $k=2$?

Comment: @Derek: Take $m = 1$, $n = 0$.  The problem doesn't state that $m$ and $n$ must be *positive* integers.

Comment: @Mike Spivey Note that the sum starts at r=1.

Comment: @Derek Jennings: Right, but then if you take $n=0$, you get an empty sum, which is 0.

Comment: See also: [What is the formula for $\frac{1}{1\cdot 2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 4}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/286024)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you've worked out your formula for $s_m-s_n,$ consider $m=(n+1)^2+n.$

Answer (score 4):

(EDIT: My original post took $p$ to be the smallest prime that divides $k$.  This is unnecessary.  You can take $p$ to be *any* number other than 1 that divides $k$.  Doing so gives you not just one solution but $d(k)-1$ solutions, one for each of the divisors of $k$ other than 1.)

(SECOND EDIT: See the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7173/) for all solutions in $m$ and $n$.)

First,
$$\frac{1}{r(r+1)} = \frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{r+1}.$$
Then $$s_n = \sum_{r=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{r+1}\right) = 1 - \frac{1}{n+1}.$$

Thus, for any $m,n \geq 1$, $$s_m - s_n = \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{m+1} = \frac{m-n}{(m+1)(n+1)}.$$

We want to find $m,n$ such that this last expression is equal to $\frac{1}{k}$.  Let $p$ be any positive integer other than 1 that divides $k$.  Take $m = (p-1)k-1$.  Clearly $m$ is a positive integer.

Then we want to show that the resulting $n$ that solves $$\frac{m-n}{(m+1)(n+1)} = \frac{1}{k}$$ is also an integer.

We have

$$\frac{m-n}{(m+1)(n+1)} = \frac{1}{k} \Rightarrow (m-n)k = (m+1)(n+1) $$
$$\Rightarrow ((p-1)k-1 - n)k = (p-1)k(n+1) \Rightarrow (p-1)k-1 - n = (p-1)n + p-1 $$
$$\Rightarrow pn = (p-1)k - p \Rightarrow n = \frac{(p-1)k}{p} - 1,$$

which means that $n$ is an integer because $p|k$.

Thus we have a family of solutions $$m = (p-1)k-1, n = \frac{(p-1)k}{p} - 1,$$
where $p$ is any positive integer other than 1 that divides $k$.

This works even in the case $k = 2$ because then we just get $m = 1$, $n = 0$.

Comment: Awesome, Mike! Apostol's problems are hard!

Comment: The special case $p=k$ gives $m=k^2-k-1,\,n=k-2$ so $s_m-s_n=\frac{(k-1)^2}{k(k-1)^2}=\frac1k$.

Answer (score 1):

First prove that $S_n=1-\frac{1}{n+1}$ by induction.

Answer (score 1):

By partial fractions it [**telescopes**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) to a sum matching the RHS of this well-known [**Egyptian fraction**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction) sum

$$\rm \frac{1}k\ =\ \frac{1}{k-1}\ -\ \frac{1}{k\:(k-1)}$$