# Calculate summation possible formula of geometric sum

Tags: summation

I need to calculate this:

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1})$

The answear is:

$1 - \frac{1}{n+1}$

But I have no idea how to get to that answear. I tried to simplify the equation to: 
$\frac{1}{kx^n+k}$
But now I don't know If I should put it inside the formula for geometric sums or if it's even possible.

Thank you!

Comment: This is not geometric!  Try writing it out for $n=2$.  Then $n=3$.  I think you'll see a pattern.

Comment: This is a [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) where the second half of one term cancels with the first half of the next term.  That leaves you with only the first half of the first term, the $1$, and the second half of the last term, the $-\frac 1{n+1}$, as they have nothing to cancel with.

Comment: See also: [What is the formula for $\frac{1}{1\cdot 2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 4}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/286024) or [Partial sum of the series $\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{r(r+1)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/7136).

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1})=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k+1}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k+1}$$
$$=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k+1}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, the formula does not simplify when you reduce to the common denominator:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k(k+1)}$$

doesn't look easier.

By if you expand a few terms using the original form, the solution all of a sudden looks trivial.